# React Native Text Input only shows input after Submitting it or moving to another field

Tags: android, ios, mobile, react-native, textinput

When I start typing the placeholder disappears but I still can't see what I type only. I can only see it when I click out of the field or submit it. I literally can't see the text that I'm typing only after I'm done which is very frustrating.

```js
// Scene
export default class Authentication extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { email: '', password: '' };
  }
        render() {
            return (
                <ViewContainer>
                    <StatusbarBackground/>
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View>
                    <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Image source={require('../Resources/logo.png')} style={styles.logo}/>
                    </View>
                    <TextInput
                      style={styles.TextInput}
                      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
                      value={this.state.email}
                      onFocus={this.onFocus}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      returnKeyType="next"
                      keyboardType="email-address"
                      placeholder="EMAIL"
                      placeholderTextColor="white"
                    />
                    <View style={styles.inputBorder} />
                    <View style={styles.inputBorder} />
                    <TextInput
                      style={styles.TextInput}
                      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
                      value={this.state.password}
                      onFocus={this.onFocus}
                      autoCorrect={false}
                      returnKeyType="done"
                      placeholder="PASSWORD"
                      secureTextEntry={true}
                      placeholderTextColor="white"
                    />
                    <View style={styles.inputBorder} />
                    <View style={styles.inputBorder} />
                    <View style={styles.buttons}>
                    <Button style={styles.login} title="Login" color="green" onPress={login}/>
                    <Button style={styles.signup} title="Signup" color="green" onPress={signup} />
                    </View>
                    </View>
                    </View>
                </ViewContainer>
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your styles? Given that you are making the placeholder text white I would like to see what color you are setting the text in general

Comment: yeah sure TextInput:{
    height: 26,
    padding: 21,
    fontSize: 13.5
  },
  inputBorder:{
    backgroundColor: '#fc5900',
    height: 1.5,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20
  },

Comment: @Khalil did you figure out a solution?